# could not concatenate string with int inside action method of url inf form tag in python Django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

`<form method="post" action="/delete_todo/{{todo_item.id}}">`

In the above code `todo_item.id` is coming from dictionary and it is integer so as i am writing it inside address of action so it is giving error that can not concatenate string with int . I could not find anyway to concatenate both with in the html in django python please help me

Comment: <form method="post" action="/delete_todo/{{todo_item.id}}">

Comment: The aboce is the code

Comment: Please add more description to the question

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question and also show your research on what you have done and what help you are looking for. The question is very generic.